# show Custom Table Separator UIView in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a dynamic Prototype TableView. As I want to show a line in the cell so I drag a uiview and placed in the cell. The problem is when I compile the app in mobile the line doesn't show up in the cell. I am doing this in my code to fill the cell values

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", 
        forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RequestTableViewCell

    cell.userNameLabel.text = firstName.uppercaseString + " " 
        + lastName.uppercaseString

    cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.tableSeparatorUIView) 
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong here

```
 cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.tableSeparatorUIView)
```

Comment: Try to set the UIView as cell contentView not as cell.UIView --- `cell.contentView.addSubview(tableSeparatorUIView)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the sample example. Use auto layout.  [Go throght sample example](https://github.com/Ashoklondhe/SampleTableView) Please go through the link. it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :-

Select your TableView  do separator None in attribute inspector. Then add UIView at bottom with height 1px and leading, trailing,bottom to tableView. .